# Python throws KeyError: \r\n

Tags: python

I'm writing a network authentication program, and when I get to the actual verification part, Python quits with the error "KeyError: \r\n." Why does Python throw a KeyError, of all things, and how can I resolve this? I'm running Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7.
Code:

```
    client.send("You should enter your username: ")
    uname=client.recv(size)
    client.send("You should also enter your password: ")
    passc=client.recv(size)
    client.send("\r\nI will verify your information.\r\n")
    if users[uname].strip(cr) == passc.strip(cr):
        client.send("It worked, continue...")
    else: client.send("It didn't work\r\n")
```

Before this, I wrote a line:

`client.send("Press return");
cr = client.recv(5)`

Edit: *slaps head* The reason it's throwing a key error is that for some reason, it won't let the client set uname. It completely ignores the client.recv there and just skips to the next line.

Comment: A KeyError means you're trying to access an item in a dictionary that doesn't exist

Comment: But I know that the item exists, for a fact. Another issue i'm having is that it skips over the uname=client.recv(size) line.

Comment: What is the item that you are convinced exists? Python is complaining that the item is a CRLF (Windows) newline; "\r\n". Are you sure that a CRLF is in the dictionary?

Comment: Okay, what happened is it's looking for uname, but uname hasn't been set, so that is my problem. It is ignoring the line that sets uname.

Answer (score 0):

You're stripping from `passc` but not `uname`. Perhaps that's the problem. Try printing `repr(uname)`.

Comment: Now it's just throwing KeyError: ''

Comment: Read the comment in the question, it is, for some reason, not settting uname

Comment: What was the client doing just before this point?  Perhaps the "\r\n" was left over from the previous message. If the client's previous message was, say, (size + 2) bytes including a terminating "\r\n", and the server read it with `recv(size)` then that "\r\n" would still be waiting in the input and `client.recv(size)` would return immediately with that "\r\n".

Comment: I think that's it, how can i clear the buffer that is holding the messages?

Comment: When receiving data of an unknown length, make sure that the size parameter `recv` is greater than the length of whatever could be sent,  so that it always returns all the data.

Answer (score 0):

If client.recv is non-blocking it will receive 0 bytes and continue. It is likely that the line is running before the server has responded